# Botão voltar do Chrome não volta a página da Home

Tags: html

Estou com um problema bem chatinho, o lance é que eu tenho um iframe em uma página

```html
<div class="iframe">
    <iframe align="top" allowtransparency="true" application="true" frameborder="0" height="360px" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="content" scrolling="no" src="Link do Iframe" vspace="0" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Ele funciona corretamente, o problema é quando eu clico no botão voltar do navegador do Chrome, em vez de ela voltar para a página principal (Home) ele permanece da mesma página que está inserido o iframe.

Ao selecionar o botão voltar e segurar, eu verifiquei que o link do iframe, de alguma maneira ficou cacheado, existe alguma maneira de eu bloquear a adição das url's (Iframe) no histórico do botão voltar?

Comment: olá, já tentou limpar o cache do navegador?

Comment: Você realmente precisa utilizar um iframe?